# What's the effect of gid of process

Tags: android, linux, uid

On android, If we set some gids on a process, the process get the privilage of the gids set on it.
For example, if we want enable a process can access internet, we can just add the uid AID_INET to the gids of this process. The androd uid is defined in filesystem/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h.

The question is:
If we add a uid to gids of a process, what effect will in the process?
Now we know:
1. The process can access the file as group via ACL;
2. some privilage is grant to the process;(as above, if AID_INET is inclued in the gids of the process, the process will have the internet access)
Is there any other effect? And how this works?

Comment: Works like in other *nix environments: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_Groups - Android is using one unique UID per app though. Groups are added to app process based on the manifest permissions to allow access to hardware resources.

Comment: Thank you. Does all effect is made by the file ACL control? I suspect there are other mechanism do it. I don't think that all the privilage can't be controled by file ACL.